# How to create a relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically, right now I have a location and a user and the relationship "follows". Both of these are a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. I have already created the user and the location in the database, but I want to connect the two when the user decides to follow a location. How do I go about doing that?

I have thought of using LocationUser.new(..), where the LocationUser is a join table of the location & user tables or Location.create(...) or something but I don't feel like either of those are doing what I want to do.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The join table should not have a model, nor a foreign key. Set `id: false` in the create_table migration.

Then, `User.locations << Location.new` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scoped additition (if you don't use a join model, a real habtm):

```
current_user.locations << @location
```

or a scoped creation (if you have a join model):

```
current_user.location_users.create(:location_id => @location)
```